# How to filter Jquery FullCalendar using Ajax reading from aspx web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

Here I am trying to filter the Event Calendar using Location. Tried with different options but no luck.  Any Help would be great. I am using one dropdown to filter the Location. On Page load it should be All and selection should filter the location and render the Full Calendar

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("eventlist.aspx/GetEvents")%>',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#fullcal').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },                   
                    defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
                    //editable: true,
                    displayEventTime: false,// hide event time 
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.EventID;
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                        event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                        event.loc = item.City;
                        return event;
                    }),
                    eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
                        return ['all', event.location].indexOf($('#location').val()) >= 0
                    }                   
                });
                $('#location').on('change', function () {
                    $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    var sval = $('#location option:selected').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{}",
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("eventlist.aspx/GetEvents")%>',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                            $.each(data,function(index,value){//for each event, I will compare the value with the filter, if true, render it.
                                if(value.City==sval){
                                    $("#fullcal").fullCalendar('renderEvent', value, true);
                                }

                            })
                        }

                    
                    });
                });
            },
    
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
            
    });
</script>
```

```html
<select id="location">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="city1">city1</option>
  <option value="city2">city2</option>
  <option value="city3">city3</option>
</select>
 <div id='fullcal'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the sequence of initialization calendar and then use function `events` in calendar to provide date by ajax. 
So first initialize calendar with property `events: function() => $.ajax({...`.
Full calendar will call your function for data. 
Then in event `$('#location').on('change'` please use function `$("#fullcal")fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`
Your function to load data has to be aware of selection from the list.

Comment: Hi Hsd, Thanks for your help. let me give a try

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#location').on('change', function () {
        InItCal($('#location option:selected').val());
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('destroy');           
    });
```

$('#fullcal').fullCalendar('destroy'); Just one line of code did the trick and shows the updated  events.